# select distinct from jsonb, left join table

Tags: json, postgresql, left-join, distinct

I have been trying to solve this for few days but it just doesn't work for me.

I have 2 tables, Report and Paper. Paper has jsonb column filled with data.
Let's say we make a yearly Report and it has a Paper inside it.
Now we can make multiple Papers, and data associated with it. (Report is here only for date, each has different year inside (2017,2018,...))

Paper jsonb column:

```json
[
   {\
    "konto": 0,\
    "kontoName": "ULAG. NA TUĐOJ IMOVINI"***,\
    "debtTurnover": 0,\
    "demandTurnover": 0,\
    "finishedBalance": 569210.27***,\
    "startingBalance": 569210.27\
  }
]
```

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWEe5.jpg)

Konto will always have the same kontoName across every Paper. (konto 1 always has kontoName "a").
The goal is to show distinct konto and names from all the Papers and join the jsonb data to the same row if jsonb data konto = distinct konto, so the data column would be an object of every Paper "finishedBalance" property.

[Result so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srCyY.jpg)

But since konto and kontoName is a collection of every Paper, it could happen the 1 paper doesnt have the konto which is displayed among distinct kontos, in that case, it should still show 0 and not nothing.)

The best scenario would be if I could somehow get complete data for 1 year in 1 row.
So there would be column year and object filled with collection of all konto/kontoNames and finishedBalance associated with them, if konto from that Paper doesn't exists in the collection of kontos, show 0 instead.

[Frontend table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOhVD.jpg)

[Code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u35mx.jpg)

First time writing something like this so my apologies for bad code.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

My solution in  the end was to use the same query but manipulate it on the backend with map(object,object), where each value index was a different Date.